# Why is FlatMap after GroupByKey in Apache Beam python so slow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Given a relatively small data source (3,000-10,000) of key/value pairs, I am trying to only process records which meet a group threshold (50-100). So the simplest method is to group them by key, filter and unwind - either with FlatMap or a ParDo. The largest group has only 1,500 records so far. But this seems to be a severe bottleneck in production on Google Cloud Dataflow.

With given list

(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
...
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
...

run through a set of transforms to filter and group by key:

```
p | 'Group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
  | 'Filter' >> beam.Filter(lambda (key, values): len(list(values)) > 50)
  | 'Unwind' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda (key, values): values)
```

Any ideas on how to make this more performant? Thanks for your help!

Comment: please report back with findings! and if the answer was useful, please select it.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting corner case for a pipeline. I believe that your issue here is on the way you read the data that comes from `GroupByKey`. Let me give you a quick summary of how GBK works.

### What's `GroupByKey`, and how big data systems implement it

All big data systems implement ways to realize operations over multiple elements of the same key. This was called *reduce* in MapReduce, and in other big data systems is called Group By Key, or Combine.

When you do a `GroupByKey` transform, Dataflow needs to gather all the elements for a single key into the same machine. Since different elements for the same key may be processed in different machines, data needs to be serialized somehow.

This means that when you read data that comes from a `GroupByKey`, you are accessing the IO of the workers (i.e. not from memory), so you really want to avoid reading shuffle data too many times.

#### How this translates to your pipeline

I believe that your problem here is that `Filter` and `Unwind` will both read data from shuffle separately (so you will read the data for each list *twice*). What you want to do is to read your shuffle data only once. You can do this with a single `FlatMap` that both filters and unwinds your data without double-reading from shuffle. Something like this:

```
def unwind_and_filter((key, values)):
  # This consumes all the data from shuffle
  value_list = list(values)
  if len(value_list) > 50:
    yield value_list

p | 'Group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
  | 'UnwindAndFilter' >> beam.FlatMap(unwind_and_filter)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It doesn't have an effect though, despite trying different variations. The problem isn't how quickly it groups, but how quickly the unwound elements are emitted from the group in the FlatMap stage - two or three per second while all other transformations are almost immediate. And I understand that it isn't parallel-able because it must necessarily be on the same machine.

Comment: what transformation do you have after the flatmap? And do you have a job id?

Comment: Sure it's a ParDo that adds a random record for each validated point, followed by another that batches the random records for a remote query. The job id is: 2017-08-26_06_10_38-4021415491644394676.

Comment: Looking at your pipeline, there's the `FetchWeather` step, which consumes the most time. Are you fetching something from an online service?
Also, it seems like you may have a *hot key* (i.e. a single key with most of the elements in the PCollection) - Do you think this is also a possibility?
If you have (hot key + fetch from external service), this means that the fetches are being mostly done serially, and that's what could be making your pipeline slow

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for taking a look. You're right that there is a hot key in this test, but in production the keys will be more or less evenly distributed. Why are the fetches from the external service done serially? I expected the system to spin up concurrent FetchWeather processes that divide the records evenly.

Comment: The fetches are done serially per key because the GroupByKey gathers all the values for one key into one machine. Then, the ParDos (Map, FlatMap, etc) that come afterwards will be *fused* (i.e. will run on the same machine and won't be parallelized). The main point is that if your production data is more or less evenly distributed, then it's not a problem to have serial fetches per key. (I feel like I did a terrible job explaining it. Let me know if I should clarify).